# Throwing ArgumentNullException, but OnThreadException is called

Tags: .net, exception

I'm throwing ArgumentNullException, but the method OnThreadException is called.
Why?
Is OnThreadException called after throwing any exception?
I work in Delphi-Prism.
How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`OnThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.onthreadexception.aspx) will be called if an exception is thrown in a Windows Forms UI thread *and not otherwise caught*. What are you expecting to catch the exception?

Comment: I'm making a project to catch the exception but instead of it, OnThreadException gets called.

Comment: Does this happen only in Windows Forms UI?

Comment: @Srcee: Yes - `OnThreadException` is a member of `System.Windows.Forms.Application`. You haven't shown how you're trying to catch the exception...

Comment: I'm trying to catch the exception by calling my method from main, and it handles it.

Comment: @Srcee: Please post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. Until you post some code, we'd basically be guessing.